# Show tooltip on selection screen mouseover event?

Tags: abap, mouseover, onmouseover, dynpro

I have defined a `SELECTION-SCREEN` and it should show a small `infotextbubble`, with self defined text over the input field, at mouse over event.

I have defined the following screen:

```
PARAMETERs: p_dfrom TYPE timestamp, "==> need the info bubble at mouse over event
            p_dto   TYPE timestamp. "==> need the info bubble at mouse over event

SELECT-OPTIONS:
              p_obj   FOR balhdr-object,
              p_subobj FOR balhdr-subobject,
              p_extid FOR balhdr-extnumber, "==> need the info bubble at mouse over event
              p_user FOR balhdr-aluser.
```

Does anyone have a minimal example for me?

THX

Comment: @Suncather `tooltip` does not work for me. The field are not `buttons`. If  `tooltip` is  a possible solution for me, than I do not know how.

Answer (score 0):

A Selection Screen is part of Dynpro technology. You may define a tooltip on each field by using the Field Property `TooltipText`: in the screen definition, go to the Attributes of the concerned field, and press the button Properties). You may assign either a Text Symbol, or a global variable.

Unfortunately, a Selection Screen is also a screen re-generated each time you activate your program and so everything you have changed in the selection screen is overwritten.

Consequently, it's highly recommended to never change manually a selection screen. I think that SAP never defines tooltips for selection screens. Too dangerous to lose manual changes at each activation.

Dynpro also became an obsolete technology because of SAPUI5/HTML/CSS/etc. So there should be no effort put in trying to do this kind of things.

Comment: @Jagger thx for your input! I was thinking of an other method, that would be adding a clickable info icon right next to the input filed (in the same line for each field) that opens a pop-up window with the information i would like to share with the user. Could you please send me a minimal example of this method? Much appreciated!